# SWIFT IF ELSE and Modulo

Tags: swift

In Swift, I need to create a simple for-condition-increment loop with all the multiples of 3 from 3-100. So far I have:

```
var multiplesOfThree: [String] = []

for var counter = 0; counter < 30; ++counter {

    multiplesOfThree.append("0")



    if counter == 3 {

        multiplesOfThree.append("3")

    } else if counter == 6 {

        multiplesOfThree.append("6")

    } else if counter == 9 {

        multiplesOfThree.append("9")

    }



    println("Adding \(multiplesOfThree[counter]) to the Array.")

}
```

I would like to replace all the if and else if statements with something like:
if (index %3 == 0)

but I’m not sure what the proper syntax would be?  Also, if I have a single IF statement do I need a .append line to add to the Array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very much on the right track. A few notes:

1. Swift provides a more concise way to iterate over a fixed number of integers using the `..<` operator (an open range operator).
2. Your `if` statement with the modulus operator is exactly correct
3. To make a string from an Int you can use `\(expression)` inside a string. This is called [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_380)

Here is the working code:

```
var multiplesOfThree: [String] = []

for test in 0..<100 {
    if (test % 3 == 0) {
        multiplesOfThree.append("\(test)")
    }
}
```

However, there is no reason to iterate over every number. You can simply continue to add 3 until you reach your max:

```
var multiplesOfThree: [String] = []
var multiple = 0
while multiple < 100 {
    multiplesOfThree.append("\(multiple)")
    multiple += 3
}
```

As rickster pointed out in the comments, you can also do this in a more concise way using a Strided Range with the `by` method:

```
var multiplesOfThree: [String] = []

for multiple in stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 3) {
    multiplesOfThree.append("\(multiple)")
}
```

Getting even more advanced, you can use the `map` function to do this all in one line. The map method lets you apply a transform on every element in an array:

```
let multiplesOfThree = Array(map(stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 3), { "\($0)" }))
```

**Note:** To understand this final code, you will need to understand the syntax around [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_112) well.

Comment: You can also increment by a stride with the `for-in` range syntax: `for test in (0..<30).by(3)`

Comment: thanks @rickster, I added that in to my answer and while I was at it I figured I would throw in a one-liner :)

Comment: If you're gonna go all functional programming on it, you can even lose the intermediate array: `let multiplesOf3 = Array(map((0..<100).by(3)) { "\($0)" })`

Comment: @rickster, good call (i was getting ambiguous use of map when I was trying to do that before, it seems that the final wrapping it in an array solves that)

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced string interpolation is the most idiomatic way to convert a single value to an otherwise-undecorated string (as opposed to `String($0)`). But that's more an issue of personal style, and tangential to this Q&A :)

Comment: You guys kick A$$!!!  Thank you!  I like the While multiple the best but thats just because I don't understand the rest yet.  So, in the console output I did a println function and it worked beautiful except that it counted to 102 instead of stopping at 99.  Any ideas?

Comment: @GonzoLoopback, I don't know what I was thinking, I just updated that part of my answer with a much cleaner version that doesn't have that problem. It also gets rid of the need to start with the -3.

Comment: Also can't you use 1...100 and that goes from 1 to 100 as a range? Seemed like Apple like that way better, but I could be mistaken as I am new to Swift.

Comment: @domshyra Apple changed the operator from `...` to `..<`. I guess for better readabity although I liked `...` a little more...

Comment: @HAS, the `...` (closed range) operator still exists. That includes the number at the top of the end of the range. It is the open range that they change the syntax of from `..` to `..<`. But this is way off topic from the original question ;).

Comment: @drewag You are absolutely right, I confused those two. Thanks for correcting me! :)

Comment: Xcode 6 beta 4 replaces `Range.by()` with `stride()`; edited answer.